# How can I make an IRC trivia channel?

Tags: irc, bots

Well the idea started with my colleagues when we decided we should study better (med school).

So we want to create and IRC Trivia bot with medical questions. The archive with the questions will be created by us. The problem is I don't really know how to make a channel and a Trivia bot. If anyone has a little bit of time to explain some of the major steps, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be one of the more easier solutions:

Prerequisite: A windows computer that is always on, to host the Trivia program.

1. Download [mIRC](http://www.mirc.com/) (a Windows client used to connect to IRC)
2. Connect to a random network, maybe best to connect to one with more than one server for redundancy.  mIRC comes with a list of networks and servers built in.
3. When you join a channel that is empty, you are basically creating it.  As long as you have someone in it at all times (such as the trivia bot in the next step) it remains open.
4. Download the [Tat's Triva Bot](http://www.mircscripts.com/cgi-bin/file.php?id=519) addon for mIRC and run it on the same computer.  Preferably, you would need a computer on all the time to ensure other people could always connect and play trivia.

You can edit the trivia questions to your liking.  Simply provide the server address and the channel name to anyone who wanted to play along.  They would of course need a client installed on their computer in order to connect, such as mIRC mentioned previously.

Alternatively, if you wanted to go down the route of creating your own IRC Network from scratch with your own domain name then it gets a little bit more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! A friend told me I could use a shell so that it stays online all the time. He told me I can find free shells. I'm from Romania, what shell do you recommend me ?

Comment: Yeah, there are plenty of free shells but nearly all of them do not allow you to run automated IRC connections (bots).  http://www.shellium.org MIGHT be free, but I'm not 100% sure.  Take a look at http://www.egghelp.org/whatis.htm and once you have the Eggdrop installed into your shell (this stays connected to IRC all the time), add-on a script such as MoxQuizz for trivia http://moxquizz.de/about.html.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Channels are maintained, on most servers, by ChanServ. You can talk to chanserv by going "/msg Chanserv [text]" (most clients alias /cs to this).

"/cs help" gives basic help, and "/cs help commands" gives a command list.