# Can I change the Trivia's Bot questions file with a command?

Tags: script, irc, mirc

It's about my medical trivia.

For example, someone wants to learn at Anatomy and not at Physiology when he enters my Trivia Channel. I want him to write !anatomy and the trivia bot should ask only anatomy questions.
I could make separate files: anatomy.txt, etc

Can someone help me out, I have no clue how to do this. I am using Tat's Trivia Bot v3.21.

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Author refers to this other question (it's about my medical trivia) : http://superuser.com/questions/32399/how-can-i-make-an-irc-trivia-channel

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for are theme rounds. You'll find the option in the Defaults tab of the Trivia Settings; it's a little button that says "Themes". Each theme has its own txt file, which you're planning on using anyway. The commands to the run themed rounds aren't as clean as you're asking, but it would be close; it would be "!trivia anatomy" or whatever theme names you have.

Hope this helps.

Nancy